# @Order (which = ) annotations before methods

Tags: java

I need my objects to be compared in the compareTo method, where the comparison is annotation dependent.

Method (compareTo) depends on the annotations placed before the getter and their order parameter.

For example, in front of the getters that return the year of birth, the first and last names may be annotated (in that order):

```
@Order (which = 3)
@Order (which = 2)
@Order (which = 1)
```

The compareTo function is to first compare surnames, in case of equality refer to the first name, in case of further equality to the year of birth.

```
@Configuration
class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

    private String name;
    private String username;
    private int birth_year;
    private int phone;
    private String email;
    private int PESEL;

    public Person(String name, String username, int birth_year, int phone, String email, int PESEL) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.birth_year = birth_year;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.PESEL = PESEL;
    }


    public int compareTo(Person p){
        //
    }


    @Order(2)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    

    @Order(1)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    

    @Order(3)
    public int getBirth_year() {
        return birth_year;
    }

    @Order(4)
    public int getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    @Order(5)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }


    @Order(6)
    public int getPESEL() {
        return PESEL;
    }

}
```

And my main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person per = new Person("Robert", "Brown", 1990, 543234234, "drfdrfdr@edu.pl", 123456789);
        per.getName().getOrder();

    }
```

Further, I do not know what to write to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Order (which = 3)
```

You don't need to use `@Configuration` annotation. It seems you need to make your own, custom annotation, that has a `which` in it and is initialized with an int value.

To use the value of `which` to order your methods, you have to use reflection API. Get all the methods from your `Person` class and simply sort them using a comparator with `getAnnotation` method and calling `which`. Watch out for methods that does not have this `@Order` annotation, as you will get a `NullPointerException`, if you try calling `which`.

Then you just invoke them on the objects and compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need annotations for that? You need the reflection API to do it, and that's notoriously slow.

Why not implement the compareTo method yourself? IntelliJ can generate code for that, and there are some nice libraries that make this very nice and efficient.

For example, the Guava [ComparisonChain](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained#comparecompareto):

```
public int compareTo(Person p){
  return ComparisonChain.start()
      .compare(this.username, that.username)
      .compare(this.name, that.name)
      .compare(this.birth_year, that.birth_year)
      ...
      .result();
}
```